# What is std::__lg?

Tags: c++, std

As title I don't know what is `std::__lg` mean after google it?And what exactly this line do : `int n = std::__lg(block_sz - pos_l + 1);`

Answer (score 12):

It's helper to compute the 2-based logarithm of integer number, i.e. it return the index of highest set bit in the number (or -1 for 0).

I.e. for 1 it will return 0, for 16 it will return 4, for 1024 it will return 10, etc.

This can be used to efficiently predict the pre-allocated size for arrays, round to the nearest power of 2 and thing like that.

Note, that as any other function starting with `__`, it's internal function of the compiler or the library, so you should not rely on its existence, such code wouldn't be portable. Other implementations of std library can come with completely different solution and different names of similar helpers (if they use something similar at all).

POSIX provides similar function - [`ffs()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ffs.3.html), there are also `ffsl` and ffsll (see the same page) which is GNU extension and work with long and long long respectively.

For the question from comment - how to use it from Java. Because of the above it's not good idea first, secondly it would require JNI wrapper for this. And third but most important - there is no reason for this actually. Java already provides similar methods [`Integer.highestOneBit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#highestOneBit(int)), although note it returns +1 in comparison to described std::__lg, i.e. 0 for 0, 1 for 1, 11 for 1024, etc.

Comment: thank you for your response! And how can I use this with JAVA?

Comment: You can't unless you create JNI wrapper for this (and still this is internal function of `std` so you shouldn't rely on its existence). Anyway, there is no point for this as Java provides the same: [`Integer.highestOneBit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#highestOneBit(int)) (returning 0 for zero, 1 for 1, so generally moved by +1)

Comment: You might also want to note that `std::__lg` is not part of standard C++.  All identifiers starting with a double underscore are reserved for the implementation (which means they can be used within an implementation of the standard library, but you can't rely on particular identifiers being in every implementation of the standard library).    Trying to create a JNI wrapper for it would be crazy, unless you're happy for your native code to be locked into a specific C++ compiler or library version.

Comment: @Peter: More precisely, all identifers with double underscores (regardless of whether they start with them) *and* all identifiers starting with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter. Additionally, at global scope, all identifers starting with an underscore, regardless of what character follows.

Comment: I upvoted this because you nicely explain the technical purpose of the function. But I think your comment is very important and should be integrated into the answer itself.

Answer (score 5):

It's an identifier used internally by your compiler (very likely GCC), because all identifiers with **double underscores** belong to the compiler implementation.

Nowhere in your own code should something like `__lg` be seen or used. Use the **interface** of the standard library, not its implementation. If your own code directly uses `__lg`, then you have no guarantee that the code will compile or do the right thing with any other compiler or even with any other version of the *same* compiler.

As the C++ standard says at §2.10 `[lex.name]`:

> Each identifier that **contains a double underscore** __ or begins
>   with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter is reserved to the
>   implementation for any use.

As for what that GCC thing actually is, just look at the [source code](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.6/a01049_source.html) which a Google search for "std::__lg" turns up.

Depending on the actual types of `block_sz` and `pos_l`, it should be either this:

> ```
> /// This is a helper function for the sort routines and for random.tcc.
> //  Precondition: __n > 0.
> template<typename _Size>
>   inline _Size
>   __lg(_Size __n)
>   {
>     _Size __k;
>     for (__k = 0; __n != 0; __n >>= 1)
>   ++__k;
>     return __k - 1;
>   }
> ```

Or this:

> ```
> inline int
> __lg(int __n)
> { return sizeof(int) * __CHAR_BIT__  - 1 - __builtin_clz(__n); }
> ```

Now, `__CHAR_BIT__` is like the standard [`CHAR_BIT`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits) macro. As [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.4/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) says:

> Defined to the number of bits used in the representation of the char
>   data type. It exists to make the standard header given numerical
>   limits work correctly. You should not use this macro directly;
>   instead, include the appropriate headers.

`__builtin_clz` is another GCC-specific function. Again, [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.2/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) explains its purpose:

> Returns the number of leading 0-bits in x, starting at the most
>   significant bit position. If x is 0, the result is undefined.

I think if you need such functionality, then it's trivial to write it yourself. In fact, the question is why you need it in the first place. The real answer to your actual problem probably lies in the code around the `int n = std::__lg(block_sz - pos_l + 1);` line.

---

Things to keep in mind:

- Do not use anything with two consecutive underscores in your own code.
- GCC is open source, so the internal implementation of special functions or macros is not secret but can easily be browsed online.